# Add & Delete an appointment / calendar entry via .ics in Outlook Calendar

Tags: icalendar, outlook-2013, nintex-workflow

**PART 1**

I am working on an `.ics` file which generates an event/appointment in Outlook:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
STATUS:TENTATIVE
.....
..........
DESCRIPTION:Absence Request
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The user gets the email with the .ics file attached. 
When opened, the user gets the following details:

[Screenshot of the ics file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwEBw.jpg)
Question:

How to disable the .ics so it does not allow to make multiple entries when the exact appointment (date) does exist?

**PART 2**

Is it also possible to delete an entry from the Outlook Calendar via the .ics file? I have tried with the following code but it does not work:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
METHOD:CANCEL
STATUS:CANCELLED
.....
..........
DESCRIPTION:Absence Request
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The cancel meeting button responds but does not actually remove the entry from the Calendar. Yes, the user can go manually and delete it from the calendar - which works fine but thought there may be an option to do via the .ics file.

I also read about the UID having to match the event but this is where I am also lacking of expertise of how to pull it from there.

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bucki, This is the difference between importing events and subscribing to a calendar (even one with one event only).

When people click on an actual ics file, calendar apps will 'import' the event/s.  I think these days some have the smarts to check the UID and not duplicate but many do not.  It depends on the app how well they attempt to detect a duplicate.  Strictly speaking one is just importing the data into one's own event in a calendar which one can then edit as one pleases.

If an ics URL is sent (not the actual file) most apps will 'subscribe' to the URL. IE:  they will create a separate calendar in the individuals calendar app.  The app will check for updates on that ics url regularly.  In that case the UID and SEQUENCE can be used to indicate a later update.  These are not editable by the user.

Comment: actually, the .ics file is send via the email as an attachment which adds (even duplicates) the event in user's Calendar. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to find the UID in this case .... by the way, I am using Nintex workflow in sharepoint 2013 to generate the ics.  As I said, the removing part can only be done directly from the calendar and not via the ICS .... I was hoping there was a way through .ics ?

Comment: by the way, I am using .ics for Outlook Calendar 2013.

Comment: What you can control via ics is:  1) what goes into the ics url or file,  2) whether the user subscribes to a url or imports an ics file.  (if files are attached to emails & not urls , then they are importing, not subscribing, with possible limitations by Outlook or any calendar app.

Comment: are you saying that IF there is way to insert the URL link within the email instead of the .ics  - then it may work ??

Comment: Possibly, probably, People still have to click the url and what they do when that happens depends on what their mail app or device does with .ics.  Usually the default is to subscribe.   ( I for eg: have .ics set to open in text editor for testing purposes ;)  but that's unusual.   )

Comment: hmmm will have to try it out some day ... if I manage to get it working, I shall mark your respond as correct/solved. :) thanks